# Not redirecting to another view controller from app delegate in swift

Tags: swift, push-notification, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I have a push notification and on the tap of it,i need to redirect to another view controller instead of home view controller.
I have written the code in app delegate method for it.
It is not redirecting to the specific view controller with which the storyboard name is mentioned.

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
                   @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
                  // Print message ID.
                  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
                      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
                  }

                  // Print full message.
                  print(userInfo)
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let presentViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageViewController") as! MessageViewController

                
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(presentViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
     

        completionHandler()
}
```

It is not redirecting to MessageViewController, instead it is going to default home view controller only.

What could the error be in the above code?

Comment: Use this : ```UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController``` insted of self.window

Comment: Above line has showed the specified view  controller,but it is not going to any other view controller from there.it is just showing that view controller

Comment: You have to push the controller not present. And also check your root controller has a navigation controller or not.

Comment: yes i got it.i changed the above code little bit.

Comment: how will it work in foreground?should i write the same code in willpresent delegate method?

Comment: I think not all push notifications we need to handle in the foreground. if you need you can do the same code. Also, you can push your destination VC on the top most view controller. You can find top most controller in stackoverflow.

Comment: This function main not be running on main thread. So you need to wrap UI methods into `DispatchQueue.main.async`